# How to make edittext like this in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have a edittext like this:

[image]

This is what I've got so far:

[image]

this is my drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#EFEFEF" />
    </shape>
</item>

<solid android:color="#EFEFEF" />
<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1.5dp"
    android:left="1.5dp"
    android:right="1.5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="5.0dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Could you help me to make a edittext like this?

Comment: apply backgroundcolor to your edittext and check

Answer (score 0):

`res/drawable/edit_text_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#EFEFEF" />
</shape>
```

This is enough to make a editText look like you have posted in image

Answer (score 0):

Try this backgroundDrawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#EFEFEF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **custom_edt.xml** and place it in **drawable** folder and give **background** for **editText**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#33b5e5" />

    <solid android:color="#FFF" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:thickness="0.5dp"
           android:shape="rectangle">
      <stroke android:width="2dp"
             android:color="#D9D9D9"/>
      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      <gradient
       android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
       android:endColor="#EFEFEF"
       android:type="linear"
       android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>



 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearchEditText"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Search text"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```